# How to delete items from cart through SESSION & AJAX in php

Tags: php, session

I am trying to remove items from cart through ajax. I am getting evrything like particular id and data in session but when i apply unset() then it is not delete that particular row. It is deleting whole cart

Here is my Ajax file Code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST);
    // echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SESSION);

    foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $product) {      
        foreach($product as $reportProduct) {
          foreach($reportProduct as $data) {
            if($data['id'] == $_POST['report_id']) {
                unset($_SESSION['shopping_cart']);  // Now how to unset that particular id session
            }
          }
        }
    }
?>
```

Here is my Cart Session Array, having two items in my cart (i.e)
print_r($_SESSION['shopping_cart']);

```
Array
(
    [shopping_cart] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 3
                                    [name] => Abbvie Emissions Report
                                    [price] => 1999.00
                                    [quantity] => 1
                                )
                        )
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4
                                    [name] => Abbvie Emissions Report
                                    [price] => 1999.00
                                    [quantity] => 1
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: why don't you index your cart with product id? Then it will be just unset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$_POST['report_id']])

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you, save your cart array like below, it's easy to manage for you instead of you showing your array.

```
Array
(
    [report_id] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => Abbvie Emissions Report
        [price] => 1999.00
        [quantity] => 1
    ),
    [report_id] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [name] => Abbvie Emissions Report
        [price] => 1999.00
        [quantity] => 1
    )
)
```

Then use the below code for the remove data from cart

**Using Loop:**

```
$shopping_cart = $_SESSION["shopping_cart"];
$temp_arr = array();
foreach($shopping_cart as $key=>$product)
{
    if($key != $_POST['report_id'])
    {
        $temp_arr[$key] = $product;
    }
}
$_SESSION["shopping_cart"] = $temp_arr;
```

**Without loop:**

```
$shopping_cart = $_SESSION["shopping_cart"];
if(isset($shopping_cart[$_POST['report_id']]))
{
    unset($shopping_cart[$_POST['report_id']]);
}
$_SESSION["shopping_cart"] = $shopping_cart;
```